# Suggestion text is not displaying in android keyboard

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-input-method

When I use inputType as "textUri", Suggestion text input is not displaying.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter URI"
        **android:inputType="textUri"**
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried using setPrivateImeOptions method but still suggest text is not displaying.
Even I used  **android:inputType="textUri|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"**
but no use.

```
  public class CompleteEditTextActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_text);

        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setPrivateImeOptions("com.android.internal.inputmethod:LatinIME");
    }
```

Comment: There are hundreds of input method editors (a.k.a., soft keyboards) for Android, including dozens of pre-installed ones. How any react to hints like `android:inputType="textUri"` is up to their developers. Personally, I would not expect to see suggestions for `textUri`.

Comment: It's client requirement to use textUri. Let me know the valid reason/proof why it is not working? @CommonsWare

Comment: "It's client requirement to use textUri" -- then do not be surprised when some keyboards do not offer suggestions. "Let me know the valid reason/proof why it is not working?" -- the developers of the particular soft keyboard you are testing decided not to offer suggestions for `textUri`, apparently. **That is their right**, as the soft keyboard is their project, not yours. You are welcome to test third-party keyboards (on the Play Store, F-Droid, etc.) and see if any happen to offer suggestions for `textUri` fields.

Answer (score 0):

It has been identified that the boolean value of shouldSuppressSuggestions has been implemented for TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI in the path

packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/InputAttributes.java

```
  // TODO: Have a helper method in InputTypeUtils
        // Make sure that passwords are not displayed in {@link SuggestionStripView}.
        final boolean shouldSuppressSuggestions = mIsPasswordField
                || InputTypeUtils.isEmailVariation(variation)
               || **InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI == variation**
                || InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER == variation
                || flagNoSuggestions
                || flagAutoComplete;
        mShouldShowSuggestions = !shouldSuppressSuggestions;
```

Hence, When we declare "textURI" in XML, the suggested word on top of the keyboard is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your codding problem its keyboard functionality...

In google Keyboard enable this settings

[image]

Comment: Even after enabling this suggestion strip, it is not working. Hence it has been identified that, for "textUri", suggestion strip has been disabled in aosp code.